# Typescript breakpoints in VS2012 fail to get hit when debugging with Chrome

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I've got a typescript game and source maps are successfully loaded in chrome and the typescript file breakpoints get hit in chrome.

However breakpoints in VS2012 fail to get hit when debugging from VS 2012.

Any ideas what to do to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only works in IE 9 and IE 10 from Visual Studio. If you use the sourcemaps, you can get debug in the Chrome Canary browser.

Comment: Can you define "it" in your last sentence? Do you mean you can get debugging to work in VS from a script running Chrome Canary?

Comment: Sorry. Not VS for that. You can use a sourcemap to help debug TypeScript in the Chrome browser, if you use Chrome Canary (unofficial builds).

Answer (score 1):

Use IE 10+ instead! thats all I can get to work right now